# Visual Studio: Combine Xamarin.Ads With Xamarin.Firebase

Tags: android, visual-studio

I am writing a chat app with Firebase integrated. The app is pretty done so far all I needed was to implement ads to my project.

I did this before in another apps. In VS I just had to download via NuGet the Xamarin.Ads (something similar) package and then I could reference it. Now, I did the same in my new app, but It seemed to be causing a problem: 
With the download of said package, all my firebase packages were removed. So, it looks like you cannot have both, right?

Now, my question is: 
What are the alternatives? Is it just a different package? I couldn't seem to find a solution to this online yet since most people use Android Studios. 
The instructions on how to use firebase with ads are always only in Java and for AS which doesnt help me much.

Is it even possible that the Ads Package deleted my Firebase packages?

Comment: If your wish is to use Admob then Admob is switched to Firebase too and you are highly recomended to use Frebase Admob instead standalone Admob SDK and I think Xamarin is providing Firebase Ads component.

Comment: Okay so here is the big problem: I found the SDK from Firebase called:
Xamarin.Firebase.Ads - This is, I think, the right SDK. HOWEVER:
if I install it, this package uninstalles a few of my other packages like "Firebase.Auth" and "Firebase.Database". Those, of course, are VITAL to my instant messaging app. Why is this happening?